# bokehjs on click callback

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I have a bokeh chart that is displaying several glyphs with the hover tool working properly on them, giving very useful information on hover.

What I need is a way of making that information persistent, i.e. not to disappear on mouse out.

A click-to-pin would work for me, but so would do a linked table with the latest clicked glyph info.

In general, it would be great I could register a `click` javascript callback to be called with the DataSource info of the element that has been clicked.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If something like [this](http://simonbiggs.github.io/electronfactors) is what you are after I did this with the bokeh [data table](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#data-table), just making sure I used the same source.

To see what I mean make sure you click on the data points. Shift click is also possible.

Comment: I ended up implementing the DataTable solution too. But I think a javascript click event would be more flexible and a better fit for my problem. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Yeah, I think something like a tooltip will come eventually.

Answer (score 1):

I tried based on [this example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#customjs-for-hover). It seems to work fine with Bokeh 0.11.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, vform
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, CustomJS
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn
output_file("test.html")

# define some points and a little graph between them
x = [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7]
y = [6, 4, 3, 8, 7, 5]

p = figure(width=400, height=400, title='Hover over points')


cr = p.circle(x, y, color='olive', size=30, alpha=0.4, hover_color='olive', hover_alpha=1.0)

# Add a hover tool, that sets the link data for a hovered circle
code = """
var data = {'x0': [], 'y0': []};
var cdata = circle.get('data');
var indices = cb_data.index['1d'].indices;

for (i=0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    // pay attention to where x and y are defined, if you define them outside for loop, 
    // it will be updated at the same time you mouse hover off the target.
    // If you want to keep the last hover on result, put x and y inside for loop.
    x = [] 
    y = []
    idx = indices[i]
    x.push(cdata.x[idx]);
    y.push(cdata.y[idx]);
}
data_table.set('data', {
    'x' : x,
    'y' : y
});
""" 

source = ColumnDataSource({})

columns = [
        TableColumn(field="x", title="x"),
        TableColumn(field="y", title="y"),
    ]

data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=400, height=280)
callback = CustomJS(args={'circle': cr.data_source, 'data_table':data_table.source}, code=code)
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=None, callback=callback, renderers=[cr]))
layout = vform(p,data_table)
show(layout)
```